# Flutter custom appbar

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to achieve the following appbar. I'm new to flutter and couldn't figure it out.
[image]

Appbar has back button on left and info icon and share button positioned at right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for right icons add `actions` to `AppBar`, arrow button is default

example

```
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('AppBar Demo'),
    actions: [
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.info),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.share),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ],
  ),
  body: Widget()...
);
```

Comment: if it worked for you, mark it as correct so other newbies can see the solution

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its helpful to you

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar( 
        leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        title:  Text('Your Title Here'),
    actions: [
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.info),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_upward ),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ],),
     
      body: Text('Ok'),
    );
```

Your Result Screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you'll have to use the scaffold Widget and invoke the following properties
**leading  property** to get the *arrow back icon*
**actions property** to place *info icon* and *ios_share icon* ..

`

Scaffold(

```
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      icon: Icon(
        Icons.arrow_back,
      ),
    ),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(Icons.info),
      ),
      IconButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        icon: Icon(Icons.ios_share),
      ),
    ],
  ),

);
```

`